# How do I call a model in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, model

I'm trying to get the hang of Laravel 5 and have a question which is probably very simple to solve but I'm struggling.

I have a controller named TestController and it resides in \app\Http\Controllers

This is the controller:

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class TestController extends Controller {

    public function test()
    {

    $diamonds = diamonds::find(1);
    var_dump($diamonds);
    }



}
```

Then I have a model I created that resides in /app:

```
<?php

namespace App;


class diamonds extends Model {


}
```

Put all other mistakes aside which I'm sure there are, my problem is that laravel throws an error:

> FatalErrorException in TestController.php line 10: Class
>   'App\Http\Controllers\diamonds' not found

So, how do I get the controller to understand I'm pointing to a model and not to a controller?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to import your model in the Controller by using namespaces.

E.g.

```
use App\Customer;

class DashboardController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $customers = Customer::all();
        return view('my/customer/template')->with('customers', $customers);
    }
}
```

In your case, you could use the model directly `App\diamonds::find(1);` or import it first with `use App\diamonds;` and use it like you already did.

Further, it is recommended to use UpperCamelCase class names. So Diamonds instead of diamonds. You also could use `dd()` (dump and die) instead of var_dump to see a nicely formatted dump of your variable.

Answer (score 3):

```
  //Your model file
  <?php
    namespace App\Models;


    class diamonds extends Model {


    }

  // And in your controller
  <?php 
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\Models\

    class TestController extends Controller {

    public function test()
    {

      $diamonds = diamonds::find(1);
      var_dump($diamonds);
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following lines above your class decleration in your controller file...

```
use App\Diamonds;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

(this assumes your model file is called `Diamonds.php`)

Comment: Dear I also used @raheel-khan code as it is to call a model. and also used danbahrami amendment in raheel khan code. but I'm facing this error **FatalErrorException in TestController.php line 4: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE), expecting identifier (T_STRING)**. I have this line on line 4: **use App\Http\Requests;**.

Comment: You need to put it before your class statement. (at the top of the file).

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, there were a few issues here and all of you helped, however I was missing the following on the model page:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
```

Comment: Oh, thanks - if you use an IDE like PHPStorm (https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) and the related laravel ide helper https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper - PHPStorm will underline missing files and suggest the namespaces for you.